# IdentityServer3 with ServiceStack and MVC Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack, identityserver3

I'm new to IdentityServer3 and am just starting to get it set up. It seems to be going quite well and I've been working on the Hybrid flow for an MVC app similar to that shown in Kevin Dockx's Pluralsight course (http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-securing-restful-api-aspdotnet) 
when I tried to configure IdentityServer with MVC error is pops up- `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: invalid_request`

ID Server:

```
new Client
{
   Enabled = true,
   ClientName = "MVC Client (Hybrid Flow)",
   ClientId = "mvc",
   Flow = Flows.Hybrid,
   RequireConsent = true,
   RedirectUris = new List<string>
   {"https://localhost:44358/"},                    
}

 var scopes = new List<Scope>{                    
    StandardScopes.OpenId,
    StandardScopes.Profile
 };
```

And the following is the code from the MVC client app

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {            
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            //CookieName = "ourcookiename"
        });

        var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "mvc",
            Authority = "https://localhost:44367/identity/",
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44358/",
            // PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",
            Scope = "openId profile"
        };
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);         
    }
```

And also have to configure `IdentityServer3` with `ServiceStack' for this I used  link`https://github.com/MacLeanElectrical/servicestack-authentication-identityserver`  to authenticate service but in  Global.aspx for new AppHost().Init(); it shows error-

```
'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ServiceStack.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Comment: You need to turn on logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I'm doing mine

```
return new[]
        {
            new Client
            {
                Enabled = true,
                ClientId = "Client",
                ClientName = "SomeClient",
                Flow = Flows.Hybrid,
                RequireConsent = true,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "openid",
                    "profile",
                    "roles",
                    "api",
                    "offline_access"
                },
                RedirectUris = new List<string>
                {
                    Constants.Client
                },

                AccessTokenLifetime = 3600,

                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>()
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                }
            }
        };


var scopes = new List<Scope>
        {

            //Identity Scopes
            StandardScopes.OpenId,
            StandardScopes.Profile,

            new Scope
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Name = "roles",
                DisplayName = "Roles",
                Description = "The roles you belong to.",
                Type = ScopeType.Identity,
                Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                {
                    new ScopeClaim("role")
                }
            },
            new Scope
            {
                Enabled = true,
                Name="api",
                DisplayName = "API Scope",
                Description = "To accesss the API",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                Emphasize = false,
                Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                {
                    new ScopeClaim("role"),
                    new ScopeClaim("id")
                }

            },

            StandardScopes.OfflineAccess

        };

        return scopes;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you specifying the AllowedScopes in your client

```
new Client
{
   Enabled = true,
   ClientName = "MVC Client (Hybrid Flow)",
   ClientId = "mvc",
   Flow = Flows.Hybrid,
   RequireConsent = true,
   RedirectUris = new List<string>
   {"https://localhost:44358/"},
   AllowedScopes = new List<string>{                    
       "openid",
       "profile"
   };                 
}
```

Comment: I added scopes but it is showing same error- `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: invalid_request`